# OK. So just how do people install a facebook application?

Tags: javascript, facebook-apps

So I've built a FB Page Tab pp which also has Canvas section. When you search for the App and selected it, you are taken to the defined canvas (with my content shown in the iframe). There is no link or button anywhere to install the app.

I use the app.facebook.com URL an navigate to the app directly. This is has precisely the same affect as the above.

I create an app page from the Advanced settings in the app center. This page only has a "Go to App" button at the top, which again simply goes to your own canvas page.

So I assume that we have to create install links ourselves and put them on this canvas page. What's the URL? I installed a complete separate application to use theirs, substituting their App id for mine. This, works and takes you to the install page for the App.

But just how are developers supposed to know this? To be more precise, just how are developers supposed to know that they are required to take care of triggering the installation process themselves.

In fact, I'm sure this isn't the case and I've simply missed something. However, something so important is not in a clearly accessible place, this much is true. I have spent an hour searching for information on what is possibly the most integral part of application deployment, and still nothing.

So for the sake of other people using google:

To allow users to install your facebook application, create a link on your canvas page with the following href url.http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[your app ipi key]&pages=1.

If someone knows if there is a setting to make searching and clicking on an app takes the user to the install page, let me know please.

Comment: This site is for questions, not dumping rants/factoids

Comment: Hence: "If someone knows if there is a setting to make searching and clicking on an app takes the user to the install page, let me know please."

Answer (score 1):

A page tab is just a page for people to view. When you set the app as a page tab it will show up in your tabs as a web page (Does not get installed as an app).

If you want it to be an app make sure you check "App on Facebook"

[image: Check App on Facebook]

Comment: Thanks. Both are already set. Sorry should have mentioned. Still no install mechanism.